# selenium - clicking a button

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to pull out the names of all courses offered by Lynda.com together with the subject so that it appears on my list as '2D Drawing  --  Project Soane: Recover a Lost Monument with BIM with Paul F. Aubin'. So I am trying to write a script that will go to each subject on http://www.lynda.com/sitemap/categories and pull out the list of courses. I already managed to get Selenium to go from one subject to another and pull the courses. My only problem is that there is a button 'See X more courses' to see the rest of the courses. Sometimes you have to click it couple of times that´s why I used while loop. But selenium doesn´t seem to execute this click. Does anyone know why?

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'http://www.lynda.com/sitemap/categories'

mydriver = webdriver.Chrome()
mydriver.get(url)

course_list = []

for a in [1,2,3]:
    for b in range(1,73):
        mydriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main-content"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[%d]/ul/li[%d]/a' % (a,b)).click()
        while True:
        #click the button 'See more results' as long as it´s available
            try:
                mydriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main-content"]/div[1]/div[3]/button').click()
            except:
                break
        subject = mydriver.find_element_by_tag_name('h1') # pull out the subject
        courses = mydriver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h3') # pull out the courses
        for course in courses:
            course_list.append(str(subject.text)+"  --  " + str(course.text))
        # go back to the initial site
        mydriver.get(url)
```

Comment: do you get `ElementNotFound` exception when trying click button?

Comment: No, it just skips it completely and goes back to the list of subjects.

Comment: oh... of course)) your `except` catch all exceptions) try to "click" your button from Python shell. Seems that webdriver can not find this button as it is not visible. You need to scroll down first to "see" the button

Comment: I suggest you to manage your commands from Python shell at first if you not sure about possible issues that can occurs

Answer (score 1):

Scroll to element before clicking:

```
see_more_results = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('button[class*=see-more-results]')
browser.execute_script('return arguments[0].scrollIntoView()', see_more_results)
see_more_results.click()
```

One solution how to repeat these actions could be:

```
def get_number_of_courses():
    return len(browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.course-list > li'))

number_of_courses = get_number_of_courses()

while True:
    try:
        button = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(CSS_SELECTOR)
        browser.execute_script('return arguments[0].scrollIntoView()', button)
        button.click()

        while True:
            new_number_of_courses = get_number_of_courses()
            if (new_number_of_courses > number_of_courses):
                number_of_courses = new_number_of_courses
                break
    except:
        break
```

**Caveat**: it's always better to use build-in explicit wait than `while True`:
http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits

Comment: Thanks. This works for the first click. But if there are more than 100 courses you have to click more than once to see all the results. I have put it into the try clause.

Comment: You are right I shown the code only for the first click - but you can easily repeat these actions till button will disappear.

Comment: I thought I was going to achieve it with while loop and try/except clause. My understanding was 1. TRY to scroll down to the button and click it as long as it's there if not (except) break from the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're calling a method to find element by class name, but you're passing a xpath. if you're sure this is the correct xpath you'll simply need to change to method to 'find_element_by_xpath'. 
A recommendation if you allow: Try to stay away from these long xpaths and go through some tutorials on how to write efficient xpath for example.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I made a mistake while pasting the code. I was experimenting with finding element by xpath or class and none of them worked. I just pasted back the xpath but forgot to change the command. I have edited my code. It still doesn´t solve my problem. Yes, I heard that long xpaths can cause problems, I will read more about it.