# Fetching a page which needs user interaction

Tags: python, web-crawler, fetch, urllib3

In Python, I am trying to fetch pages from a specific website.
In this website, there are some parts in which the information is not completely accessible in the HTML page, and needs a bit of user interaction. To be more clear, there are some reviews, but the long reviews are shortened, and to see to whole review user must click on 'More' hyperlink. Is there any way to handle these hyperlinks in Python and fetch the whole reviews for all those cases?

Here is a snapshot of the 'More' hyperlink:

```
<span class="bla bla" onclick="ta.util.cookie.setPIDCookie(123); ta.call('ta.servlet.Reviews.expandReviews',event,this,'review_331979201', '1', 123);"> More </span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use selenium webdriver api for example see this

https://www.reddit.com/r/selenium/comments/2lscf4/clicking_a_button_using_selenium_python/

for read complete docs use http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/

Answer (score 1):

Use `Selenium` python binding: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/

The algorithm may be following:

1. If "More" hyperlink is not visible in view port - scroll to this element
2. Click to hyperlink
3. Fetch all reviews

The similar case for scrolling and clicking on web element: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34271050/2517622